# Concatenate Variable Onto Form Input Value Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, concatenation

I have a PHP `while` loop that generates a table containing `input` tags. Each input box is given a unique name by appending the input box name and the loop value.

```
<?php
$i=1;
$r=0;
while($i<=$positionjobrows)
{
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?PHP echo $i; ?>
        </td>
    <td>
    <input type=text NAME="position<?PHP echo $i; ?>" id="position<?PHP echo $i; ?>"  style="border: 1px solid #2608c3;color:red; width=200px" value="<? echo mysql_result($resultpositionjob,$r,0);?>"> 
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type=text NAME="job<?PHP echo $i; ?>" id="job<?PHP echo $i; ?>"  style="border: 1px solid #2608c3;color:red; width=200px" value="<? echo mysql_result($resultpositionjob,$r,1);?>"> 
    </td>
    <td>
    <SELECT NAME="person<?PHP echo $i; ?>" id="person<?PHP echo $i; ?>" style="border: 1px solid #2608c3;color:red; width=200px" onchange="get(<? echo $i; ?>);"> 
    <OPTION VALUE=0 >
    <?=$optionpeople?> 
    </SELECT>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div id="training<?PHP echo $i; ?>"><font color=grey size=2>Training details will be shown here</div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?PHP
    $i++;
    $r++;
    }
    ?>
```

I am trying to modify my javascript / jquery script to use each of the generated input box names.

For example the input box position will be named position1, position2, position3 etc. I call the script using onchange="get(row)" where row is the loop instance. so for position1 the onchange will be onchange"get(1)"

This is passed to my javascript / jquery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function get(row){

        $.post ('getpeopleinjobs.php',{ 
        postvarposition: form.[position+row].value,
        postvarjob: form.job+row.value, 
        postvarperson: form.person+row.value, 
        postrow: row}, 
            function(output){
                $('#training'+row).html(output).show();
                    });
        alert(postvarposition); 

        }

</script>
```

As you can see, I want to set the variable postvarposition to the `id` of the inputbox (position) + the row number. I want to concatenate the two together inside the `form.position.value` statement. So get(1) will then produce:

```
postvarposition: form.position1.value
```

My thinking is along these lines, but is not working:

```
postvarposition: form.[position+row].value,
```

How can I concatenate the name of the inputbox against the row?

Thanks as always for the help.

**UPDATE**

This code below works for the first row where I manually append '1' to the input tag name.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function get(row){
        alert(row);
        $.post ('getpeopleinjobs.php',{ 
        postvarposition: form.position1.value,
        postvarjob: form.job1.value, 
        postvarperson: form.person1.value, 
        postrow: row}, 
            function(output){
                $('#training'+row).html(output).show();
                    });
                }
</script>
```

I have then tried to change it as advised by machineghost but this still doesnt work. I have confirmed that the value of variable row is 1 with the alert message.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function get(row){
        alert(row);
        $.post ('getpeopleinjobs.php',{ 
        postvarposition: form[position+row].value,
        postvarjob: form[job+row].value, 
        postvarperson: form[person+row].value, 
        postrow: row}, 
            function(output){
                $('#training'+row).html(output).show();
                    });
                }
</script>
```

Google Chrome (F12) ouputs error `Uncaught ReferenceError: position is not defined`

any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the bracket syntax you can't combine it with period syntax.  In other words:

```
form.[position+row].value
```

should be:

```
form[position+row].value
```

Answer (score 0):

Working 100% now.

should be

form["position"+row].value as per advice from machineghost.